# Get Action method result status in Ajax

Tags: java, jsp, jquery, struts2

Here is the situation

In my JSP page, I am calling an action class method

```
<input type="text" class="inputstyle" name="feedName" id="feedName" placeholder="<s:text name="global.feed_name" />" required>
```

Here is my Ajax JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#feedName').blur(function() {
            var feedName=$("#feedName").val();
            if(feedName!="")
            {
                $.ajax( {
                      traditional: true,
                      type: "POST",      
                      url: "feedCheck",
                      data:"feedName="+feedName,
                      dataType: "text",
                      success: function(response) {
                          alert("AVAILABLE!");
                      },
                      error: function(data) {
                          alert("NOT AVAILABLE!!!");
                      }       
                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="feedCheck" method="feedCheck" class="com.analytic.webapp.action.AAIDCAIndexAction">
            <result name="success">DCAAnalytix.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">DCAAnalytix.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Action Class method

```
public String feedCheck()
    {
        MClient client = (MClient) getRequest().getSession().getAttribute(
                AAI_CLIENT);
        List<String> feedNamesFromDB=mFeedManager.getAllFeedNameByClient(client.getClientKey());
        System.out.println(feedName);
        if(feedNamesFromDB.size()>0){
            if(feedNamesFromDB.contains(feedName)){
                return ERROR;
            }
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

The ajax call is working fine and calling the action class method and it executes. But the problem is, the result always goes to error in Ajax. That is, if the method returns **SUCCESS** then also the webpage alerts with **"NOT AVAILABLE!!!"**

I am new to Ajax. When I searched, most posts are about returning JSON data too. I don't want JSON data. I need the result status only and how to get that in Ajax?

Comment: Which version of struts are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result type of ajax in struts2 should be a stream. Try with this in your code.

```
<action name="feedCheck" method="feedCheck" class="com.analytic.webapp.action.AAIDCAIndexAction">
  <result type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
    <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

And in you action class.
You should create class variable with getter and setter

```
private InputStream inputStream;
```

and then in your method

```
public String feedCheck()
{
    MClient client = (MClient) getRequest().getSession().getAttribute(
            AAI_CLIENT);
    List<String> feedNamesFromDB=mFeedManager.getAllFeedNameByClient(client.getClientKey());
    System.out.println(feedName);
    if(feedNamesFromDB.size()>0)
    {
        if(feedNamesFromDB.contains(feedName))
        {
            this.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(ERROR.getBytes()));
        }
        else
        {
            this.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(SUCCESS.getBytes()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(SUCCESS.getBytes()));
    }

    return SUCCESS;

}
```

Hope this will work.

And in your view page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#feedName').blur(function() {
            var feedName=$("#feedName").val();
            if(feedName!="")
            {
                $.ajax( {
                      traditional: true,
                      type: "POST",      
                      url: "feedCheck",
                      data:"feedName="+feedName,
                      dataType: "text",
                      success: function(data, success) {
                          if(data.indexOf("success")==-1){
                                  alert("Action returned Error")
                           }else{
                                 alert("Action returned Success") 
                           }
                      }      
                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

The stream data will returned String "error" or "success". And it will available in your success method of ajax in view page.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is coming to success only. It does not going to error even it is setting to error in Action class method(Always shows **"AVAILABLE!"** alert). Do I need to change anything in Ajax Jquery script? Thanks

Comment: The first condition is always gets correct. That is `if(response.indexOf("success")==-1)` becomes true always and alerts its corresponding message

Comment: Please do a debugg in your action method and see what it is returning. The string what returning from that method will only availabe inside your ajax sucesss. Also you can monitore the request and response of ajax through firebug of mozilla.

Comment: I did debug and it is returning error when condition is true. I did
`alert(response.indexOf("success"));
           alert(response.indexOf("error"));`
And both dispalys with **"-1"**
That is why it's content inside `if` is displaying

Comment: Answer edited please check ajax function in jsp page ' success: function(data, success) {
'

Comment: No. It is still the same. Do I need to return the result like `return getInputStream();` in the method? Now my method return type is `void`